# RedirectMatch rule exception using PCRE

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, http-redirect

I have a working RedirectRule to which I want to add an exception.  Here is the current RedirectRule:

```
RedirectMatch (?i)/.+menu\.html$ http://www.foobar.com/foobar.html
```

I would like to exempt ext3270-Menu.html from this rule.

I found the following example at https://serverfault.com/questions/189666/make-exception-to-whole-site-redirectmatch-rule:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/?((?!(thisisfoo|thisisbar)).*) https://www.foobar.com/$1
```

I was hoping someone who is more adept than me at PCRE could respond with something similar that would meet my requirements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said `PCRE`, use negative lookahead to see if there is no `ext3270-Menu.html` in your URI.

```
(?i)^/(?!.*ext3270-Menu\.html).+menu\.html$
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nT0eC6)

Comment: Thanks.  One question I understand this to read as NOT .*ext3270-Menu\.html followed by .+menu\.html to the end.  If so could this be simplified as (?i)^/(?!.*ext3270).+menu\.html$

Comment: Yes you can simplify in that way. Basically it is checking `if there is no ext3270 in url` then match for `.+menu\.html$`